# Random result except self in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$random = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
```

Where by `$random` I'm getting related result of my products.

#### The issue is:

If I'm visiting `product two` page in my random section I see `9 other products` + `product two`

#### What I want is

To see totally `10 different products` and not see `product two` in my random section **while I'm visiting `product two page`**

How can I do that?

Comment: Without sufficient information to give a specific answer, basically you need to modify your query so that when on "product xxx" page, the query has a `WHERE product != 'product_xxx'` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [WHERE NOT IN] in SQL?

```
$random = Product::whereNotIn('id', [$product->id])
->inRandomOrder()
->limit(10)
->get();
```

Comment: thanks it is working, `just for knowledge`  if i have only `2` product and i'm visiting one the other one will repeat `10` times as we have `limit(10)` is there anyway in that case just show my random once and not `10` times?

Comment: wow I can't see why this happen.
But if you wanna fix it. Try handle it in Php:

`$random = array_unique($random->toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` to filter

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$random = Product::where('id', '!=', $product->id)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```